# baseAdapter in android and inflate different layouts

Tags: android

I've write a simple program for `GridView` and I have Problem with `Counter` variable.

when I use `pos_word[counter]` it not work but when I use number in it, its works. like `pos_word[1]`
I want to write a adapter to inflate different layout in `gridView`.

Can you help figure it out

```
package com.example.crossword;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CrossWord_Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public int length = 9;
    public int[] pos_word = {0,3,4,5,6};
    public int counter = 0;

    public CrossWord_Adapter(Context context) //difination -------|
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        holder layoutHolder;

        if(position == pos_word[counter])
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_word, null);
                layoutHolder = new holder();
                layoutHolder.word = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_word);
                convertView.setTag(layoutHolder);
                if(counter < pos_word.length)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        else
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_hashur, null);
            }   

        return convertView;
    }

    class holder
    {
        TextView word;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length` is 9. and `pos_word.length` is 5.

change

```
if(counter < length)
```

to

```
if(counter < pos_word.length-1)
```

Comment: ohh sorry, when I take some test to find problem I made this mistake, I've change it but not works again !!!!

Comment: what is result? crash it?

Comment: yes, when `counter` is 4 you increase it. and then `counter=5`. I will edit my answer. you should check `if(counter < pos_word.length-1)`